# How would I confirm two zip files are of equal content when they have different metadata?

Tags: go, hash

I currently have a database storing the hash of a zip files byte array, I intend to compare it to the hash of a new zip file in order to determine if the zip files have the same content, however as a result of the metadata being different the hashes produced are different.

Does anyone know a way I can get around this?

(Coding in go and database is in gcp)

I have also tried using the length of the byte array as a possible way to validate however it occasionally varies by one or two for some reason and wouldn't be as rigorous.

Comment: Not possible. Apart from header differences, the files could be arranged in different order inside the ZIP and compressed with different algorithms and/or different compression levels. The only (sane) way to know if two ZIPs with different hashes are the same is to decompress their content.

Comment: You could however parse the header, iterate the content and compare/hash the compressed data for each file (if both the compression level and algorithm match). That'd be quite tedious to code though. Maybe there are some libraries that allow you to iterate over the compressed stream of all the files one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the files you can compare the hashes of unzipped files. If this isn't a one time thing, it might be good to add that hash to the database as well (I wouldn't remove the zipped hash though).

If you don't have access, I don't think this would be possible for the reasons Marco listed.